# Find multiple maximum values form a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have read answers to similar questions but I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

I will use a simple example to demonstrate my question.

I have a table called 'Prizes' with two columns: Employees and Awards

The employee column lists the employee's ID and award shows a single award won by the employee. If an employee has won multiple awards their ID will be listed in multiple rows of the table along with each unique award.

The table would look as follows:

```
Employee      AWARD
    1     Best dressed
    1     Most attractive
    2     Biggest time waster
    1     Most talkative
    3     Hardest worker
    4     Most shady
    3     Most positive
    3     Heaviest drinker
    2     Most facebook friends
```

Using this table, how would I select the ID's of the employees who won the most awards?

The output should be:

```
Employee
   1
   3
```

For the example as both these employees won 3 awards

Currently, the query below outputs the employee ID along with the number of awards they have won in descending order:

```
SELECT employee,COUNT(*) AS num_awards
FROM prizes
GROUP BY employee
ORDER BY num_awards DESC;
```

Would output:

```
employee  num_awards
  1       3
  3       3
  2       2
  4       1
```

How could I change my query to select the employee(s) with the most awards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to express this is using `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT employee, COUNT(*) AS num_awards,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM prizes
      GROUP BY employee
     ) p
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Being able to combine aggregation functions and analytic functions can make these queries much more concise.

Comment: This works perfect thanks. Would I be correct in assuming that I could also remove 'COUNT(*) AS num_awards' from the select statement as it's not really useful? EDIT: In my actual query I only need the employee's ID with the most awards and not how many they actually won.

Comment: @Shiftz . . . You can remove the `count(*) as num_awards`.  Also, just `select employee`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dense_rank` to get all the rows with highest counts.

```
with cnts as (
SELECT employee, count(*) cnt
FROM prizes
GROUP BY employee)
, ranks as (select employee, cnt, dense_rank() over(order by cnt desc) rnk 
            from cnts)
select employee, cnt 
from ranks where rnk = 1
```